# Dropdown not disable when radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

It's supposed to be working but unfortunately it isn't. I don't know what is wrong with my code. When I try in jsfiddle , it's working but in my Notepad++ it doesn't works. I can't figure out what's wrong with this.

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $('input:radio[name="senior"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val()=='Yes') {
            $('#seniordis').attr('disabled',false);
        } else


            $('#seniordis').removeAttr('disabled', true);
    });
    </script>



</head>



Senior : 

<input name="senior" type="radio" id="Yes" value="Yes" />Yes
<input name="senior" type="radio" id="No" value="No" selected="selected" />No<br />  
<select name="seniordis" id="select">
<option value="100" >100% discount</option>
<option value="50">50% discount</option>
<option value="10">10% discount</option>
</select>                  
</td>
```

Comment: use  $('#seniordis').prop('disabled',true) instead of $('#seniordis').attr('disabled',true);

Comment: @AbuHanifa , nothing changed

Comment: Use onclick event instead of change

Comment: remove attr('disabled',true); use .hide()

Comment: @MichaelAngeloJopia let me know if my answer helps

Comment: @MichaelAngeloJopia if the selected answer is the right answer then how on earth would it work in your fiddle? when the id in the jquery selector  itself is wrong.. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Your problem is,  `senoirdis` is name not a id. Your id is `select`.

```
$().ready(function()
{
    $('input:radio[name="senior"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val()=='Yes') {
            $('#select').prop('disabled',false);
        } 
        else
        {
            $('#select').prop('disabled',true);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the code. **The issue is with the way you are referencing the libraries**. Change the references to have a `https://`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

It is not working in your Notepad++ because you are viewing this file in the brwoser which will have the `file://` request and not `https://`. It works in your fiddle because there you might be referencing the library in different way but **Valid way**.

Also pointing out a mistake in your code.

This line `$('#seniordis').removeAttr('disabled', true);`

Here `seniordis` in the value of name attribute of your select tag and not the id if it... so use Either `$('[name="seniordis"]')` to target the element by name or `$('#select')` to target the element by id.

So the code should be

`$('#select').attr('disabled', true);`

OR this

`$('#select').removeAttr('disabled');`

Answer (score 0):

There are some Errors with your code

1. This line

   ```
   input:radio[name="senior"]
   ```

   Must be this

   ```
   input[name=senior]:radio
   ```
2. This Line

   ```
   $('#seniordis').attr('disabled',false);
   ```

   Must be

   ```
   $('#select:input').removeAttr('disabled');
   ```

Use code Below:

```
<div>
    <input name="senior" type="radio" id="Yes" value="Yes"  />Yes
    <input name="senior" type="radio" id="No" value="No" />No<br />
    <select name="seniordis" id="select">
        <option value="100">100% discount</option>
        <option value="50">50% discount</option>
        <option value="10">10% discount</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[name=senior]:radio").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
            $('#select:input').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#select:input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input:radio[name="senior"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
        $('select[name="seniordis"]').attr('disabled',false);
    } else {
        $('select[name="seniordis"]').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e39Lsu2f/)

Comment: why is it working in jsFiddle ? but in my notepad++ not? i dont know what the problm @symlink